# Request for MySQL all keywords with meaning and example on how to use it

Tags: mysql

Is there anyway can get a complete list of MySQL6.0 keywords with meaning and examples? As the result I get from google is just a list only but no meaning or example.

Comment: Let us google it for you

Comment: it would be great if you can help XD thanks first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL 5.7 is the last version.

You can find a lot of documentation here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/

For example: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/func-op-summary-ref.html is a list of functions and operators.